# substrate forkless upgrade tutorial, pallet_scheduler has breaking changes

Tags: substrate

I am following https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades/ and have added

`pallet-scheduler = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }` to my `Cargo.toml`.

It seems that this appears to be a newer version and requires me to specify `NoPreimagePostponement` and `PreimageProvider` in `pallet_scheduler::Config`.

Here is the exact error message:
`error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: PreimageProvider, NoPreimagePostponement`

What should I set those value to be? https://docs.rs/pallet-scheduler/latest/pallet_scheduler/trait.Config.html doesn't seem to also have those properties and I'm guessing that the crate hasn't been published yet.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ is a much better place to ask for help - and I really suggest reporting an issue / bug on github for the docs on this -https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/ BUT there is a new version of the site, so URLs have changed!

Answer (score 0):

[The associated pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10356) mentions the changes necessary. In short, just set the following to imitate the desired behavior:

```
type PreimageProvider = ();
type NoPreimagePostponement = ();
```